Triple actions shortcuts (Single, Double, Hold) with combination of single key and modifier keys
I have been looking for triple action (Single tap, Double tap, Hold) shortcut mapping method that I can easily tweak and assign with AHK and I have finally found this amazing solution.

This single, double and hold AHK script is not working

It is almost perfect but one issue is that I can't use modifier keys as mainKey.
For Illustrator, There's a lot of limits when it comes to customizing shortcuts.
Some of them are hard coded which I can't change at all and it doesn't even allow me to use ctrl or alt keys for Tools' shortcuts.
What I am trying to do is, I assign shortcut "Shift+1" to Selection Tool, "Shift+2" to Lasso Tool and mapping the shortcuts with AHK.
Like, when pressing "Ctrl+Space", it triggers "Shift+1" so I can use Selection Tool and "Ctrl+Double Tap Space" for "Shift+2" which is Lasso Tool.
This way, I can use Ctrl key for Tools.
TripleBind(mainKey, msec, singleKey, doubleKey, holdKey)
{
  ProcessPress(key)
  {
    static count := 0
    held := true
    ++count
    AfterTime()
    {
      if (held) {
        Send holdKey
      } else if (count == 1) {
        Send singleKey
      } else {
        Send doubleKey
      }
      count := 0
    }

    if (count == 1) {
      SetTimer AfterTime, -1 * msec
      KeyWait mainKey
      held := false
    }
  }

  Hotkey "$" . mainKey, ProcessPress
}

TripleBind("space", 300, "Numpad1", "^+!v", "+q") ---This works fine
TripleBind("^space", 300, "Numpad2", "^+!b", "+w") ---This doesn't work

With the script I can assign any keys with modifier keys (i.g ^+!v, +q, etc.) for the singleKey, doubleKey and holdKey, but I can't assign them for mainKey. mainKey seems to work with only a single key without modifer keys.
I need the mainKey works with any modifier keys (ctrl, alt, shift or all of three at once).
What parts should be added or modified to achieve it?

Try this:
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1

$Space::
Hotkey := SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 2)
Switch, Morse()
{
Case "0":MsgBox,,, %Hotkey%, 2
Case "00":MsgBox,,, Double %Hotkey%, 2
Case "1":MsgBox,,, %Hotkey% Hold and release, 2
Default:MsgBox,, %Hotkey% Pattern without Case,% Pattern, 2
} Return

^Space::
Switch, Morse()
{
Case "0":MsgBox,,, Ctrl+Space, 2
Case "00":MsgBox,,, Ctrl+DoubleSpace, 2
Case "1":MsgBox,,, Ctrl+Hold and release Space, 2
Default:MsgBox,, Ctrl+Space Pattern without Case,% Pattern, 2
} Return

Morse(Timeout = 400) {
    Global Pattern := ""        
    Win := WinExist("A")
    RegExMatch(Hotkey:=A_ThisHotkey, "\W$|\w*$", Key)
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    MouseGetPos, X1, Y1, Win1
    While, !ErrorLevel {
        T := A_TickCount
        KeyWait %Key%
        Pattern .= A_TickCount-T > Timeout
        KeyWait %Key%,% "DT" Timeout/1000
        MouseGetPos, X2, Y2, Win2
        IF (Win key Hotkey Win1) <> (WinExist("A") A_PriorKey A_ThisHotkey Win2)
        Or 30 < (X2-X1)**2+(Y2-Y1)**2
            Exit
    } Return Pattern
}

